# Reducing size of user avatars? - creating thumbnails

Tags: php, image-manipulation, thumbnails, avatars

User of my site upload images which are used as avatars. I have set a upload limit size of 2 MB. At most places I only require thumbnails. But users upload images with far bigger resolutions. I store these files on my file-system.

How can i create thumbnails and store them instead of large sized files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your installation / server setup, you have several possibilities.

- You could use the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), and something like its [`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) function
- Or you could use the [`Imagick extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), and something like its [`thumbnailImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-thumbnailimage.php) method.

I would say that I've quite never seen a server without GD installed -- for Imagick, its less likely to be installed by default :-(

Another solution might be to call the [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) command-line utility *(it comes with ImageMagick -- independantly of any PHP extension)*, using something like [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to call it.

Advantage, with that, would be that you wouldn't be limited by `memory_limit`, as the resizing would be performed by an external tool -- but, of course, it also means that your application will rely on an external tool, which is not always nice...

If necessary, there are plenty of tutorials about GD ; for instance, those might interest you :

- [How to create thumbnails with PHP and gd](http://icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/) : it uses a batch process to generate thumbnails for many images -- which might be useful if you have to generate thumbnails for all images that you already have
- [Thumbnail generation with PHP tutorial](http://www.webxpert.ro/andrei/2009/01/08/thumbnail-generation-with-php-tutorial/) : does some stuff not often seen, like create square thumbnails, by centering the orignal image and adding some background color.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [GD module](http://php.net/gd) or the [ImageMagick module](http://php.net/imagick) to resize and shrink any uploaded images.

If you google around for something like "PHP image resizer", you'll find lots of examples.  I tend to use GD, as I have an old bit of code kicking around that works just fine.  Assuming you have a known uploaded jpeg image found at `$srcImgPath`, you could do something like the following, where `$newWidth` and `$newHeight` are the new sizes of image you want:

```
list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($srcImgPath);
$srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($srcImgPath);
if ($srcImg === false) return false;
$workImg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($workImg,$srcImg,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($workImg,$newFilename,$quality);
```

Functionalize as appropriate, and be sure to specify the `$quality`.  You can abstract this code out to handle gifs and pngs very easily as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the gd library, specifically the [imagecopyresized function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note, if you go down the GD route, use imagecopyresampled, as it produces cleaner looking images. By that I mean it won't look as grainy and/or pixely.

Link to the PHP manual on the function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend the timthumb.php script. it is rock solid.
http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/

Comment: It contains a serious security flaw http://markmaunder.com/2011/08/01/zero-day-vulnerability-in-many-wordpress-themes/ though so make sure you get the most recent one from http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

Answer (score 0):

If you have Imagick installed in your PHP setup. Then there is a function that does this. [Imagick::thumbnailImage()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-thumbnailimage.php)

If you don't have Imagick, then the GD library will come in handy. Since they have [imagcopyresized()](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Google AppEngine fitted with a subset of PIL? There is the 'resize' function that could be use... and best of all, you are getting a free quota!

Comment: But I am not using Google AppEngine.